# Merge List into parent list by concatenating the values in APEX

Tags: apex

I am having two list

```
 List<Monitoring__c> objCase =  [Select Id from Monitoring__c where ApplicationLicenseId__c =:appID];

           List<String> monitoringId=new List<String>();
            for(Monitoring__c a : ObjCase){             
                monitoringId.add(a.id);
            }

 List<Task> objTask=[select status__C from Task where Monitoring__c in : monitoringId]   ;
```

First List will give some ID and with that I am generating second list. The second list will have more than one value for one id. SO after fetching this I want to concat all the values respective to that id and have to insert that value by finding the id in first list.

Output for first list

```
_   Id
----------
a0K0w000000Kp4XEAS
a0K0w000000KpAxEAK
a0K0w000000KpBeEAK
a0K0w000000KpBUEA0
a0K0w000000KpD1EAK
```

```
Task__c             Status__c      Name
0K0w000000Kp4XEAS   Incomplete    Inbound
0K0w000000Kp4XEAS   Pending       Outbound
0K0w000000Kp4XEAS   Appeal         Extra
```

Might be my logic is incorrect . Can you please guide me for some suggestins to get it done

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you want to create a mapping of Monitoring Id to tasks that are related to the monitoring id?

Comment: Yes. You are right

Answer (score 0):

To create a mapping of Monitoring Id to tasks, you can do the following:

```
List<Monitoring__c> objCase = [Select Id from Monitoring__c where ApplicationLicenseId__c = :appID];

Map<Id, list<Task>> monitoringIdToTaskList = new Map<Id, list<Task>>();
for(Monitoring__c a : ObjCase){             
    monitoringIdToTaskList.put(a.id, new list<Task>());
}

if (!monitoringIdToTaskList.isEmpty()) {
    for (Task t : [select Monitoring__c, status__C from Task where Monitoring__c in :monitoringIdToTaskList.keyset()]) {
        list<Task> taskList = monitoringIdToTaskList.get(t.Monitoring__c);
        taskList.add(t);
        monitoringIdToTaskList.put(t.Monitoring__c, taskList);
    }
}

system.debug('Monitoring Id to tasks mapping: ' + monitoringIdToTaskList);
```

Comment: will this  for (Task t : [select Monitoring__c, status__C from Task where Monitoring__c in :monitoringIdToTaskList.keyset()]) cause any governer limits?

Comment: In short, no. Because there is an if statement that checks whether the monitoringIdToTaskList list is empty or not. If the list is empty, the for loop won't run.